# pickle.load Error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte ... invalid start byte

Tags: python, pickle

I have a pickle file dictionary containing numpy arrays which looks like:

```
{'test': array([[-0.18496349, -0.45449205, -0.48359153, ..., -0.04512954,
    -0.07903713, -0.22708473],
   [ 0.56156779,  1.7704169 ,  1.64386864, ..., -0.04512954,
    -0.07903713, -0.22708473],
   [-1.40342229, -1.13582737, -1.07386949, ..., -0.04512954,
    -0.07903713, -0.22708473],
   ...,
   [ 0.39234589, -0.6842755 , -0.58197119, ..., -0.04512954,
    -0.07903713, -0.22708473],
   [-0.1559453 , -0.3456116 , -0.21304746, ..., -0.04512954,
    -0.07903713, -0.22708473],
   [-0.18435258, -0.68987475, -0.70494576, ..., -0.04512954,
    -0.07903713, -0.74499316]])}
```

I can read the pickle file successfuly in Python 3.6 as:

```
with open('test.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

I then write this data to be read in Python 2.7 as:

```
with open('test_2.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f, protocol=2)
```

Then when I try to read the file in Python 2.7 as:

```
with open('test_2.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

I get this error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 2576890457: invalid start byte`.

I tried to convert the keys in the `data` dictionary to ascii or unicode before saving the pickle file and it did not change the error.

**Update:**
The dtype of the numpy arrays are float64, I noticed that if I cast the numpy arrays to `float32` I can load the file in Python 2.7. Is there any reason `float64` is problematic here?

Comment: Did you try loading `test_2.pkl` in python 3.6? Can you show us the content of the dictionary you dumped?

Comment: Yes I can load `test_2.pkl` in python 3.6. I edited the post to show the content of the dictionary.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have different versions of numpy in the two python installations and the `array` objects therefore reconstructs differently. Otherwise try falling back to protocol=0.

Comment: hmm, both numpy versions are 1.14.5! Thanks for the suggestion, but I still don't understand the reason this does not work.

Comment: This work if I fall back to protocol=0. Not surprisingly it takes very long to load the data.